# How can I use telnet from Emacs in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, emacs, telnet

There does not seem to be a built in Telnet client for Emacs. I am using Windows 7. I would either like to run:

M-x TELNET

: or I would like to run "telnet" from shell or eshell

Answer (score 2):

You can [combine eshell with tramp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-se/EshellAndTramp). In eshell, use `cd /telnet:host.example.com:/remote/path` to browse a remote directory. (Do you really want telnet and not ssh?)

I'm not sure if Windows's `telnet.exe` utility would work in a `M-x term` buffer. Windows terminals (consoles) behave differently from unix terminals (ttys), and emulating a Windows console inside a program is difficult. The [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) telnet program would work, though (and so would the Cygwin ssh program).